# Пытаюсь заполнить базы данных MYsql через Textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

При нажатии на кнопку для заполнения бд происходит ошибка `Fatal error encoutered during command execution`

Код программы

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SD = System.Data;

namespace DBredaction
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public MySqlConnection mycon;
        public MySqlCommand mycom;
        public string connect = "Server=localhost;Database=catalog;Uid=root;pwd=;charset=utf8;";
        public SD.DataSet ds;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                
                string sql = "INSERT INTO  employee (id, imia , familia , otchestvo, telephon)" +
                "VALUES (@id, @imia, @familia, @otchestvo, @telephon);";
                mycon = new MySqlConnection(connect);
                mycon.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mycon);
                //создаем параметры и добавляем их в коллекцию
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 5);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imia", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@familia", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otchestvo", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                mycon = new MySqlConnection(connect);
                mycon.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("DB CONNECT");
                mycon.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection lost");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: На какую из кнопок вы нажимаете? У вас тут 2 обработчика. В какой строке возникает исключение? У вас в запросе объявлено 5 параметров, а заполняете вы только 4.

Comment: `id` это что - PRIMARY KEY, для него стоит AUTO INCREMENT? если да, то его не следует передавать в запрос вообще, база данных должна заполнять его сама.

Comment: @aepot - кажется, Ваш последний комментарий решает проблему в вопросе. Офмите как ответ?

Comment: @S.H. это гадание на кофейной гуще, а не ответ. Стеклянный шар показал судьбу.

Comment: Уважаемый автор вопроса, внесите ясность в студию! Решает совет в комментарии Вашу проблему?